# Yoroi Chrome plugin wallet is not syncing

Tags: wallet, yoroi, syncing

My Yoroi wallet is not syncing even after running `Resync Wallet`. It has been many days and the wallet seems to not have made any progress. Is complete restoration the only way out of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with Emurgo servers. You might want to reach out to their support [at their website](https://yoroi-wallet.com/#/support).

**Scam warning: never, never, NEVER trust anyone on social media, always go to the Yoroi official site to reach their suport.**

Answer (score 1):

Their backend is probably down, in the meantime you can use your recovery phrase to restore your wallet on another platform, like [Daedalus](https://daedaluswallet.io/en/download/) or [Adalite.io](https://adalite.io/)